# Naked redirect doesn't work on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, web, dns

I have a bit of an issue here that I can't resolve. I have 2 domains linked to my Heroku account (slng.co and slangthis.com) and one of them has an SSL on it (not sure how relevant that is). First domain - shrt.co - is used as a link shortener domain and the other - loooong.com - is used as the "normal" domain. So whenever someone types in shrt.co/something, they should be re-linked to looong.com/something.

If I make a get request to www.shrt.co it does the redirect as it's supposed to, but if I type in shrt.co I don't get a response... most of the times at least. Sometimes I do get re-directed to looong.com. Same story for looong.com. Sometimes I get re-directed to www.looong.com and sometimes I get no response.

Any suggestions on what I might be doing wrong here? I'm not sure if I should be looking at my DNS settings or my heroku app. Any suggestions?

Edit:

Here's the DNS information for the two domains. The first one is the short url domain and the second one is the "real" domain. I've also set the short url domain to forward to the long url domain if that helps:

[image: Short url DNS]

[image: Normal url DNS]

Answer (score 0):

More inputs as your DNS settings and how you are making these redirects, for example, would help us help you :)

But maybe this rack middleware help you achieve what you want: https://github.com/tylerhunt/rack-canonical-host

It's what I use to do redirects between multiple domains on a Heroku hosted app.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I've added some more information above. I'm still not sure why this is happening and why it's only happening half the time. Any suggestions?